# How to disable Volume Mixer in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers, volume-mixer

I want to disable the Volume Mixer so that my volume is controlled by one slider. Is that possible?

[image]

I'm sick of turning on my main volume really high to hear YouTube, only to switch to another program (like a video game) and lose my hearing, then realized it was because the volume mixer set my Chrome to 5% but my game to 100%. I'm not even sure how the volume mixer gets set because it gets overridden by other programs (and I don't know when that happens).

Answer (score 1):

IT appears when you manually set a volume it will stay relative to the Speakers volume like this
[image]

[image]

What You can do is set all the volumes to 100%
then when you move the speakers volume slider it should change all of them
like this

[image]
[image]

Let me know if this solves your issue.
Is it also only chromes volume that is offset?

Comment: Ya, I know about this trick but it was looking for a way to disable it completely or better yet have a simple button that resets/sync all the levels to the main volume. This method isn't ideal if music or sound is already playing on your computer (unless you want to go deaf at 100% volume for a brief second). Thanks though.